# how to add a click to a json value

Tags: javascript

I have built a dynamic html table from "json" using javascript.
I would like the `investmentNo` value to be a link that would display a dynamic modal table with duration, date, and time when clicked.

```js
var myInvestment = [{
    "investmentNo": "00032",
    "amount": "70000",
    "status": "Running"
  },
  {
    "investmentNo": "00033",
    "amount": "40000",
    "status": "cleared"
  },

  {
    "investmentNo": "00034",
    "amount": "5000",
    "status": "Rejected"
  },

  {
    "investmentNo": "00035",
    "amount": "40000",
    "status": "Approved"
  }
];

var investmentTable = document.querySelector("#investmentTable");
var noOfInvestment = myInvestment.length;

if (noOfInvestment > 0) {
  var col = []; // define an empty array
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfInvestment; i++) {
    for (var key in myInvestment[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
  var tHead = document.querySelector("#tableHead");
  // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
  var hRow = document.querySelector("#tableRow");
  // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
  tHead.appendChild(hRow);
  investmentTable.appendChild(tHead);
  // CREATE TABLE BODY .
  var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
  // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
  for (var i = 0; i < noOfInvestment; i++) {
    var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD .
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = i + 1;
    bRow.appendChild(td);

    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = myInvestment[i][col[j]];
      bRow.appendChild(td);
    }
    tBody.appendChild(bRow)
  }
  investmentTable.appendChild(tBody);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full-pagination table-responsive" id="investmentTable">
  <thead id="tableHead">
    <tr id="tableRow">
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%;" id="serialNo">S/N</th>
      <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="investmentNo">Investment No</th>
      <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="amount">Amount</th>
      <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="status">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: make investmentNo  a class to have it click for all rows, and add a click event for '.investmentNo '

Comment: Alternatively, the element to add links, in HTML, is called "A". You will need to do a call to `document.createElement("A")`, append the resulting element to `td` and modify the `innerHTML` of your new element instead of that of the `td` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help

```js
var myInvestment = [{
    "investmentNo": "00032",
    "amount": "70000",
    "status": "Running"
  },
  {
    "investmentNo": "00033",
    "amount": "40000",
    "status": "cleared"
  },

  {
    "investmentNo": "00034",
    "amount": "5000",
    "status": "Rejected"
  },

  {
    "investmentNo": "00035",
    "amount": "40000",
    "status": "Approved"
  }
];

var investmentTable = document.querySelector("#investmentTable");

myInvestment
  .forEach((item, i) => {
    var row = investmentTable.insertRow();
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = i + 1;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = `<a href="google.com/${item.investmentNo}">${item.investmentNo}</a>`;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = item.amount;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = item.status;
  });
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full-pagination table-responsive" id="investmentTable">
  <thead id="tableHead">
    <tr id="tableRow">
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%;" id="serialNo">S/N</th>
      <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="investmentNo">Investment No</th>
      <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="amount">Amount</th>
      <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;" id="status">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: This works. the investmentNo now appears as a link but still not showing a modal table when clicked on.@JayVaghasiya

Comment: @chibuogwu i just show you how to add dynamic table with any HTML tags in better way, so now you can do rest, you can add button and on click of button you can show modal